# Помогите составить условие: если в url есть категория "/en/", то выводится текст на английском

Tags: php

Подскажите, как будет выглядеть условие.

Есть "site.ru/ru/" с текстом на русском языке, при переходе на англ. язык урл меняется на "site.ru/en/". Иногда фрагменты текста остаются на русском языке (заголовки спойлеров, например). Хочу перевести их с помощью условия:

```
if (url содержит /en/);
echo 'английский текст';
else echo 'русский текст';
```

Как прописать это условие: "**url содержит /en/**"?

Если есть какие-то другие способы перевода, их тоже рассмотрю.
Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: Ваш способ увеличивает объем кода, и он становится не читабельным. И потом его поддерживать - это полный ужас.

Comment: Друзья, благодарю за ответы! Этот способ использовать не пришлось - разобрался с кодом и сделал всё по-человечески. 

Пообщаешься со знающими людьми и появляется некоторая ясность)). Спасибо!!

Comment: > Цитата: разобрался с кодом и сделал всё по-человечески

Красавчик, уважуха и респект!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Способов море:**

1. Использовать Ваш "ужасный" способ. Править/расширять языки будет проблематично и ресурсоемко.
2. Хранить переводы в БД. Для каждого языка создать по БД: project_ru и project_en. Либо все в одной бд.
3. Создать языковые файлы, на уровне обычных php файлов. Данный способ легок в понимании и реализации.

Если проект небольшой, то советую **использовать 3-й способ.**

*П.С. забудьте Ваш способ. Привыкайте сразу к хорошим вещам!*

Comment: Понимаю, что способ ужасный; использую его из-за недостатка знаний.

Сайт создан на CMS MODx, перевод организован модулем YAMS. Там в коде можно что-то исправить, чтобы все непереведённые фрагменты переводились, но мне это не сделать. Утешаю себя тем, что таких фрагментов мало.

Comment: Благодарю за критику! Полностью согласен. Потихоньку изучаю php, во время работы с проектами. У меня другая специальность).

Answer (score 1):

[strpos](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php)

```
$mystring = '/en/dsad/dsa/dsa/';
$findme   = '/en/';
if(strpos($mystring, $findme)!==false) {
echo 'английский текст';
} else {
echo 'русский текст';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getLang()
{
    $uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    return $uri[1];
}

if (getLang()=='en')
....
```

Вообще, посмотрите, что содержит массив `$_SERVER` через `print_r($_SERVER)`, например.